# How to deploy an existing PerformancePoint dashboard to a new site?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, business-intelligence, performancepoint

Apologies if the question is not worded appropriately.

I've created a dashboard using the dashboard designer and succesfully deployed it to our development server. Now I'd like to deploy it to our staging server - is there a way to do that?

I've tried pointing the designer at a different URL without success.

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into same issue and thanks to Umair for reminding me about the import option with the Dashboard Designer.  You will open up designer in new location and then use the Import option and point to your ddwx file.

Here is the posting and references from the forum posting - [Deploy PPS 2010 dashboard content to new server](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ppsmonitoringandanalytics/thread/2b9c7333-6729-45e7-a27d-81b7fd04ff32)

I have an additional link in the forum post at the bottom that will send you to the link to the technet documentation as well.

Comment: You're absolutely right - totally forgot I had this question open.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have SSAS reports and SSAS data sources then the [PerformancePoint 2010 Content Deployment Tool](http://ppscd.codeplex.com/) might be of help.

I have used it to deploy dashboards and reports to another server without issues. It even lets you deploy remotely from dev to other servers if you have the needed permissions. Pretty neat tool, sadly it hasn't been updated recently and still lack a few key features (as the ones I described above).

PPS in SP2013 comes with this built in, but I haven't studied the details yet. Just picked it up from the PPS team in [this blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2012/08/03/what-s-new-in-performancepoint-services-2013.aspx)

Never figured out a good way to deploy SP lists data connections and SSRS reports though.